# If Grindelwald saw the future then why was the bloodpact ignored?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Grindelwald's skull had the phrase 'For the greater good 1898' written on it. But Dumbledore invented this phrase in 1899 in his letter to Grindelwald.

That means Grindelwald could see the future, like the way he shows the world war scene.

Then why didn't he see the future and observe the bloodpact being stolen by Newt's animal.

Comment: Just because he could see the future doesn't mean he's omnipresent. And that's assuming he _can_ see the future.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yes. But bloodpact is very important right?

Comment: It just means Dumbledore can't fight Grindelwald. Which is important but it's not really necessary for Grindelwald's plans.

Comment: [Why do you think Dumbledore invented it?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+the+greater+good)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I believe you mean omniscient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Grindelwald is a Seer (https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/810753569808875520), that does not make him omniscient.

As Professor McGonagall says in Prisoner of Azkaban:

> > “Divination is one of the most imprecise branches of magic. I shall not conceal from you that I have very little patience with it. True Seers are very rare, and Professor Trelawney…”

Even centaurs (who seem to be much more skilled at divination than poor Sybill Trewalney), do not always have definite answers and are not remotely all-knowing.

As a Seer, Grindelwald may see glimpses of large events in the future but he would not know every minor detail of the future.